# Remotely calling show desktop in Windows using SSH

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file, ssh

I'm SSHing from Unix to a Windows 7 Professional PC running Bitvise SSH Server. I'm then viewing the Windows 7 machine via VNC.

When I SSH in I can issue many commands but I struggle with trying to minimise all desktop windows on the target machine.

I want to call a script that **shows the desktop** of the Window 7 PC using my SSH connection. I've tried quite a few options which I'll list and I'm struggling for more ideas. I think the main nub of the matter is that I'm not actually SSHing in to a connection that contains an instance of the desktop I am currently using.

1. Call an SCF script
   I saved this code in an SCF file on the desktop and called it. No errors returned but no success either.

   ```
   [shell]
   command=2
   iconfile=explorer.exe,3
   [Taskbar]
   command=ToggleDesktop
   ```
2. Run a VBS script
   My next idea was to run a vbs script. Again I put the following in a vbs script on the desktop and called it. Again no errors and again no success either.

   ```
   Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   Shell.MinimizeAll
   ```
3. Powershell Script
   This I copied to a ps1 file with the same results

   ```
   (New-Object -ComObject shell.application).toggleDesktop()
   ```
4. Use a batch file. So then I tried running all in batch file. Again no errors and no success.

I believe the commands are completing its that they are in a different instance of the desktop to my logged in instance I am viewing with VNC.

Can you offer any suggestions?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I dunno, man.  I thought I was on to something with using scheduled tasks to run interactively with the desktop.  But in testing, all commands succeeded with no effect on the active windows appearing in VNC.  Maybe you could use AutoIt to run in the back ground and poll for a file; and if that file appears, delete it and toggle the desktop.  Or maybe you could have a window minimized and running `waitfor` to wait for a signal you can send via the ssh console, toggling the desktop and looping back to the beginning when the signal is received.

Comment: Ahh, that's an interesting idea. It's a shame there isn't a proper solution but that could work. Never thought of using a file as a signal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command you are looking for is this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c “%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Shows Desktop.lnk”
```

...which can probably be shortened to this:

```
cmd /c “%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Shows Desktop.lnk”
```

I haven't tested this using VNC, but I would think it should work since it evaluates the %appdata% directory and actual location of the shortcut itself, so I wouldn't expect it to fail to work for the current session.

I also realize you said you're using Bitvise, but for those using Cygwin, I found another solution that will also work:

```
$ showdesktop="$(cmd /c "ECHO %appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Shows Desktop.lnk")"
$ cmd /c "@start "$showdesktop""
```

There are a few other ways you could go about trying to accomplish this, another possibly by using VBScript's SendKeys in order to mimic WinKey+D.